# How to parse with SimpleDateFormat correctly?

Tags: java, date

I have this exception with this code:

`java.text.SimpleDateFormat@42ee54java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Dec 25 02:00:00 EET 2020"`

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> addEvent(@Valid @RequestBody Event event) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        format1.parse(String.valueOf(event.getDate()));
        format1.setLenient(false);
        eventService.save(event);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(event, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | ParseException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Due to date format is defined correctly. What can be wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: thans to everybody!

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What is the type returned from `event.getDate()`? Asking because it may look like you are converting a `Date` to a `String` only to parse it back into a `Date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set Locale, like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

because of **Fri Dec** in your input string and your default locale is probably not english